# C++: Issue with output

Tags: c++

I have the following code for a C++ program designed to do the following:   Develop and run a program that has two functions that find the maximum value – (call it findLargest) in an array and the minimum value (call it findSmallest) in an array. The code compiles without issue but the output does not display properly, i get a series of repeating numbers that read "-9.25596e+61" If someone could help me troubleshoot this issue it would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

```html
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

double findLargest(const double LIST[], int);
double findSmallest(const double LIST[], int);
void printArray(const double LIST[], int);


int main()
{
 cout.setf(ios::fixed);
 cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
 cout.precision(2);

 const int MAX = 10;

 double list[MAX] = { 32, 54, 67.5, 29, -34.5, 80, 115, 44.5, 100, 65 };   // elements for the array
 printArray(list, MAX);

 cout << "\n\nThe largest number is: " << findLargest(list, MAX);
 cout << "\n\nThe smallest number is: " << findSmallest(list, MAX) << "\n\n";

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

double findLargest(const double LIST[], int size)                //function to evaluate the largest elements and output it out
{
 double largest = LIST[0];
 for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
 {
  if (LIST[a] > largest)
  {
   largest = LIST[a];
  }
 }
 return largest;
}


double findSmallest(const double LIST[], int size)     // function to evaluate the smallest and output it out
{
 double smallest = LIST[0];
 for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
 {
  if (LIST[a] < smallest)
  {
   smallest = LIST[a];
  }
 }
 return smallest;
}

void printArray(const double LIST[], int size)                   // function to print array
{
 cout << "\n\nThe size of the element is: " << size << "\n\n";
 for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
 {
  cout << setw(9) << LIST[a];
  if ((a + 1) % 8 == 0)
   cout << endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this with a debugger, maybe try using gdb. Look for some tutorials online. It will also help you debug in the future.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and I had to `#include <iomanip>` before it would run, because otherwise `setw()` was undeclared.  However, after I included that file, the program ran just as it should.  Are you including `iomanip` anywhere in your program? If not, that may be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your problem is that you need to include the file:

```
<iomanip>
```

Add the line:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

to the beginning of your code and see if that helps anything.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @JustinHartley Yea, no problem man.  Are you using a debugger?  If not, you should. My debugger picked detected your problem right away; I couldn't even run your code without including `iomanip`.